# Mercurial - way of getting the altered files from a set of changesets?

Tags: mercurial

I have tagged a set of code to be uploaded to our server.

However, I'm wondering about the options to maintain it afterwards. Theoretically Mercurial's changesets could be used to 'export' all the files that have been changed since the tagged changeset, so that following subsequent builds I only need to upload the files that have been changed.

Is this possible?

Comment: What operating system are you on? If on Windows, there's a tool called ROBOCOPY that will help you mirror the contents of one directory into another. This could be used to upload new and changed files without involving Mercurial. I'll look at the Mercurial command though to see if I can see a way to find what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer, I am indeed on Windows so I'll check out Robocopy. I do like the hg diff solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably several ways of getting that list of files, but here's one:

```
hg diff --stat -r TAG:
```

This will output something like this:

```
[C:\Dev\VS.NET\DiffLib] :hg diff --stat -r 27:
 .hgignore                                           |    2 +
 Binaries.fbp7                                       |  Bin
 Binaries.fbpInf                                     |   13 +-----
   ...
 19 files changed, 370 insertions(+), 41 deletions(-)
```

---

Here's another, using the log command with XML output:

```
[C:\Dev\VS.NET\DiffLib] :hg log --style=XML --verbose -r 27:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry revision="27" node="fc6db773ccbb335cc11f42ea4588adea6b179cd8">
<author email="lasse@vkarlsen.no">Lasse V. Karlsen</author>
<date>2010-11-30T12:03:38+01:00</date>
<msg xml:space="preserve">Ensured &quot;.orig&quot; files are ignored.</msg>
<paths>
<path action="M">.hgignore</path>
</paths>
</logentry>
<logentry revision="28" node="a1f739dd59a73d37ff058f3cc89e0b42d535bee5">
<author email="lasse@vkarlsen.no">Lasse V. Karlsen</author>
<date>2010-11-30T12:17:06+01:00</date>
<msg xml:space="preserve">Changed to .NET 3.5 to support more projects. Impl
e&lt;T1,T2&gt;</msg>
<paths>
<path action="M">DiffLib.Tests/DiffLib.Tests.csproj</path>
<path action="M">DiffLib/AlignedDiff.cs</path>
<path action="M">DiffLib/DiffLib.csproj</path>
<path action="M">README.markdown</path>
</paths>
</logentry>
```